# Favicon not showing because of lat google core update?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, favicon

recently my favicon stoped showing in the google search, and I didn't do any modification. It appears when I enter the page with a 200 OK in the console.

The problem started when Google did its core update. Does anyone has/had the same problem ?
If you did, what did you do to put it back ?
Thanks !